# Is this possible to do in 1 mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all the app names from this table

```
SELECT id, name FROM app_names
```

And using that data fetch these results

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users_dailyrecords WHERE day='x' appName='THE ID FROM THE SELECT ABOVE'
```

And with the result of that query I want to insert it into

```
INSERT INTO app_stats (appID, day, totalUsers) VALUES ('appID', 'x', 'RESULT FROM count(*)')
```

I could easily write a php script to do this but I think it can be done pretty easily using mysql queries.

Comment: yes, there is such thing as INSERT SELECT statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can combine all of these:

```
INSERT INTO app_stats(appID, day, totalUsers) 
    SELECT 'appID', 'x', count(*)
    FROM users_dailyrecords
     WHERE day = 'x' AND
           appName IN (name FROM app_names);
```

It is unclear what the `appName` part is doing.  Presumably, the only appnames in `users_dailyrecords` should be valid ones in `appName`.  This sounds like a good place for a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Yeah the appName isn't needed I forgot to remove that when posting this. This query makes sense and I think it should work. My only question is, will this insert just 1 record? I have about 80 records inside the app_names table and I would like to insert the stats for every app.

Comment: This will insert all records returned by the `select`.  You can run the `select` by itself to see them.

Comment: Awesome, this is so much prettier then a few selects and php loops.

Comment: Okay I just tried this and it works if I remove the count(*) but with the count in there it only returns 1 record.